# How do I make a folder have recursive permissive access (rwx for every user and no owner) regardless of who creates files/folders and when?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have a folder called `/shared` on the root level of my file system. I want to store files in there and user/file permissions are not important.

I am using Fedora 38

I can do `sudo chmod -R 777 /shared` and `sudo chown -R nobdy:nobody /shared` however newly created files will have the permissions of the user that created them.

Is there a way to have that folder enforce a policy that allows rwx for everyone, regardless of when/who creates files?

Comment: [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165865/forcing-owner-on-created-files-and-folders) may be a more detailed answer for what you want

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing called "no owner" in Unix.

The closest thing to what you want to do is to put all users who're supposed to have access to that directory into a special group - for instance `shared` - and then use the "directory setgid" on all directories.

So basically

```
chown -R root:shared /shared
find /shared -type d | xargs -I DIR chmod 2775 DIR`
```

Make sure **NOT** to make any of the *files* setgid, only the directories.

What the setgid bit (mode `2000`) on a directory does is that it makes all newly created files and subdirectories inside it owned by it's current group.

Unless you also set the sticky bit on that directory, everybody in that group will be able to delete files in it that were created by another user.

You also need to tell your users not to set their `umask` from being too restrictive - you'd want something like `umask 0002` and not the default `umask 0022`.

---

Depending on your file system and operating system, you could also use something like `setfacl`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl

However, that is not a portable solution and it isn't supported on BSD.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, one way to do this in linux is using access control lists with `setfacl`, see also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306851), like this:

```
setfacl -d -m o::rwX .
setfacl -m o::rwX .
```

The owners will still be preserved, but anyone will be able to add/delete/modify any files inside the directory (and subdirectories) where you run this command.

Another way is to use a file system that doesn't support permissions in the first place, like vfat. The best is to have a separate partition where you will have this directory, and:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/<partition>
sudo mount -o umask=0 /dev/<partition> /shared
```

(and add this in fstab of course, to have it mounted on reboot).

If you can not spare a partition, you could use a raw image file as a loop device:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=10000 of=vfat.img
mkfs.vfat vfat.img
sudo mount -o loop,umask=0 vfat.img /shared
```

(this will make a 10MB image, you can change the size in the `count` argument)